# Color progression issue in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have three different turtles: red, white, and green. I am trying to get these turtles to couple up (like people in relationships) and then uncouple. While a red turtle is coupled with a green or white turtle I want the patch color to sometimes randomly change colors, but for some reason the patch color color progression is not working.

```
to go
  ask turtles
    [ if coupled? = true
        [ set couple-length couple-length + 1 ] ]
  ask turtles
    [ if coupled? = false
        [ move ] ]
  ask turtles
    [ if coupled? = false and shape = "person righty" and (random-float 10.0 < coupling-tendency)
        [ couple ] 
    let potential-intervener one-of (turtles-on neighbors) with [ green-dotter? = true]
    if (coupled? = true and potential-intervener != nobody and "person righty" = true)


[ifelse (random-float 10.0 < resting-tendency)

  [;;decides to stay
    ask potential-intervener [move-to patch-here] ;; this is possibly what is causing the lack of intervention?

    ; does not intervene, start the color progression
    ifelse (random-float 10.0 < intervening-tendency)
  [;; intervenes
    uncouple
  ]
    [set couple-length couple-length + 1 ;; increments the couple length by 1
    if (couple-length = 2)
    [
      ask patch-here [set pcolor yellow]
      ask patch-at -1 0 [set pcolor yellow] ]

    if (couple-length = 4)
    [
        ask patch-here [set pcolor orange]
        ask (patch-at -1 0) [set pcolor orange] ]

    if (couple-length = 6)
    [
      ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
      ask (patch-at -1 0) [set pcolor red] ] ]
  ]
  [
    ;;decides to move
    ask potential-intervener [move]

    set couple-length couple-length + 1 ;; increments the couple length by 1
    if (couple-length = 2)
    [
      ask patch-here [set pcolor yellow]
      ask patch-at -1 0 [set pcolor yellow] ]

    if (couple-length = 4)
    [
        ask patch-here [set pcolor orange]
        ask (patch-at -1 0) [set pcolor orange] ]

    if (couple-length = 6)
    [
      ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
      ask (patch-at -1 0) [set pcolor red] ] ]
  ]
  ; will green dotter intervene?
  ifelse (random-float 10.0 < intervening-tendency)
  [;; intervenes
    uncouple
  ]
  [;; does not intervene, start the color progression
    set couple-length couple-length + 1 ;; increments the couple length by 1
    if (couple-length = 2)
    [
      ask patch-here [set pcolor yellow]
      ask patch-at -1 0 [set pcolor yellow] ]

    if (couple-length = 4)
    [
        ask patch-here [set pcolor orange]
        ask (patch-at -1 0) [set pcolor orange] ]

    if (couple-length = 6)
    [
      ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
      ask (patch-at -1 0) [set pcolor red] ] ] 
]

  check-sliders
  tick
end
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `css`?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your line `if (coupled? = true and potential-intervener != nobody and "person righty" = true)` is inside a command block that is only reached through `if coupled? = false and shape = "person righty" and (random-float 10.0 < coupling-tendency)`. That is, it doesn't get reached because coupled? would need to be both true and false. Better formatting would make this immediately clear. I have reformatted the top part of your code so you can see this:

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse coupled?
    [ set couple-length couple-length + 1 ] ]
    [ move
      if shape = "person righty" and (random-float 10.0 < coupling-tendency)
        [ couple ]
      let potential-intervener one-of (turtles-on neighbors) with [ green-dotter?]

      if (coupled? and potential-intervener != nobody and "person righty")
        [ ifelse (random-float 10.0 < resting-tendency)
          [;;decides to stay
            ask potential-intervener [move-to patch-here]
```

A couple of other notes. You don't need to say `if coupled? = true`, it is sufficient to say `if coupled?`. Since you have the same colouring code three times, it would be better to have it only once as a separate procedure and call it from the three locations, so it is much easier to change.